# BASH: Is there a simple way to check whether a string is a valid SHA-1 (or MD5) hash?

Tags: regex, bash

It's all in the title.

An alternative way to phase the problem is: in BASH, what is a concise way of checking whether a string is a sequence of 40 (or 32) characters in the ranges `[0-9]` and `[a-f]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a function:

```
is_valid() {
    case $1 in
      ( *[!0-9A-Fa-f]* | "" ) return 1 ;;
      ( * )                
        case ${#1} in
          ( 32 | 40 ) return 0 ;;
          ( * )       return 1 ;;
        esac
    esac    
  }
```

If the *shell* supports *POSIX character classes* `[![:xdigit:]]` could be used instead of `[!0-9A-Fa-f]`.

Comment: +1 elegant, succinct, idiomatic, and I believe POSIX `sh` compatible (except not sure about the opening paren in the `case`s).

Comment: Could you please comment what is not Bourne Classic compatible in @aioobe's solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Philippe, neither the [[ shell keyword, nor the =~ operator are standard.

Comment: @tripleee, thanks! The opening paren is optional, but standard, see [SUS](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), *Case Conditional Construct*.

Comment: Some old shells might also prefer `[!0-9a-f]` over `[^0-9a-f]`. And you probably want to include the uppercase case (sic).

Comment: Thanks @tripleee, I often erroneously use ^ instead of ! in this context :) Corrected. (A-Fa-f content is locale sensitive).

Answer (score 9):

Try this for 32 characters:

```
if [[ $SOME_MD5 =~ ^[a-f0-9]{32}$ ]]
then
    echo "Match"
else
    echo "No match"
fi
```

Comment: Won't this also match any hex string with trailing or leading non-hex characters? Delimiting with ^ and $ should handle that case.

Comment: This test returns a match for string from 0 to 32 characters. I think that if you want to check for 32 characters exactly, you need `^[a-f0-9]{32}$`.

Answer (score 1):

```
stringZ=0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF01234567

echo ${#stringZ}
40
echo `expr "$stringZ" : '[0-9a-fA-F]\{32\}\|[0-9a-fA-F]\{40\}'`
40
```

Then, test if `${#stringZ}` equals `expr "$stringZ" : '[0-9a-fA-F]\{32\}\|[0-9a-fA-F]\{40\}'` and it should be true if the string is 32 or 40 characters and only hexadecimal digits.

Like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
stringZ=""
while [ "$stringZ" != "q" ]; do
    echo "Enter a 32 or 40 digit hexadecimal ('q' to quit): "
    read stringZ
    if [ "$stringZ" != "q" ]; then
        if [ -n $stringZ ] && [ `expr "$stringZ" : '[0-9a-fA-F]\{32\}\|[0-9a-fA-F]\{40\}'` -eq ${#stringZ} ]; then
            echo "GOOD HASH"
        else
            echo "BAD HASH"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
[ 07:45 jon@host ~ ]$ ./hexTest.sh 
Enter a 32 or 40 digit hexadecimal ('q' to quit):
1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef
GOOD HASH
Enter a 32 or 40 digit hexadecimal ('q' to quit):
1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef01234567
GOOD HASH
Enter a 32 or 40 digit hexadecimal ('q' to quit):
1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef0
BAD HASH
Enter a 32 or 40 digit hexadecimal ('q' to quit):
123
BAD HASH
Enter a 32 or 40 digit hexadecimal ('q' to quit):
abcdef
BAD HASH
Enter a 32 or 40 digit hexadecimal ('q' to quit):
0123456789ABCDEF0123456789aBcDeF98765432
GOOD HASH
Enter a 32 or 40 digit hexadecimal ('q' to quit):
q
[ 07:46 jon@host ~ ]$
```